# Have to create simple calculator, calculation is done using eval(). I can't figure out how to send the answer to the text box

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I had to create a simple calculator to handle basic math problems. I created the calculator using a table, and a text form to hold the solution. Each button is supposed to set the variable inputString equal to the return value of the `updateString()` function.

```
<table class = "calculator">        
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'>
            <form action="">
                <div class="calc">
                    <input type="text" value=""/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>    
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="1" onclick="inputString =  updateString('1');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="2" onclick="inputString = updateString('2');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="3" onclick="inputString = updateString('3');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='/' onclick="inputString = updateString('/');"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="4" onclick="inputString = updateString('4');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="5" onclick="inputString = updateString('5');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="6" onclick="uinputString = updateString('6');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='*' onclick="inputString = updateString('*');"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="7" onclick="inputString = updateString('7');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="8" onclick="inputString = updateString('8');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="9" onclick="inputString = updateString('9');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='-' onclick="inputString = updateString('-');"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value="0" onclick="inputString = updateString('0');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='.' onclick="inputString = updateString('.');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='C' onclick="inputString = updateString('C');"/></td>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='+' onclick="inputString = updateString('+');"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="calc" type="button" value='=' onclick="document.forms[0].value = eval(inputString);"/></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

This is the function that I created to handle the updating of the String with each button press

```
    function updateString(p1){
      var inputString;
      inputString += p1;
      return inputString;
    }
```

Comment: What element are you wanting to place the value in?

Comment: @mwilson, `<div class="calc"><input type="text" value=""/></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to the input field

```
<div class="calc">
    <input id="outputBox" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

And set it's value to the `inputString`

```
function updateString(p1){
  inputString += p1;
  document.getElementById("outputBox").value = inputString;
  return inputString;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eL78fvLb/3/)

The final calculation (`=`) works the same way

```
onclick=" document.getElementById('outputBox').value = eval(inputString);"
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. But what would I need to put into the = buttons onClick to make the text box display eval(inputString)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of your question, to solve it, you can use `JQuery` that'll allow you to display the returned value in the DOM

```
function updateString(p1){
    var inputString;
    inputString += p1;
    $('.your-text-box').val(inputString);
}
```

Comment: Why would you add jQuery for such a simple problem?